# Trigger second function in toggle()

Tags: toggle, jquery

Is there a way I can call the second function in  `toggle(function(){},function(){})`

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this ?

Comment: I have a toggle with two functions and for a specific case I want the second function to be called and set the state of the toggle() to the second function

Comment: I show how to do this below, but wouldn't using a named function, reversing the order and calling that now-first named function be easier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* skip the toggle to the next function, if you really wanted to I suppose, for example:

```
$("div").toggle(function() {
    alert("First");
}, function() {
    alert("Second");
})​;
```

Then you can manually advance the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function array (*without* calling the first function), like this:

```
$("div").data('lastToggle' + $("div").data().events.click[0].handler.guid, 1);
```

Then just click the element or `$("div").click()`, etc, and it'll fire the second function.

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JyPVN/), note that this only works in jQuery 1.4+ and is really just to show it's possible.  You should however either bind them in reverse order, or give the second argument a named function as the other answers suggest.

Comment: @Avinash - If you look at how `.toggle()` works internally it's much easier to understand: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L904 All we're doing it setting a data variable it's looking for when the `click` event happens.  The `click` isn't bound to *any* of the functions you pass, rather it's bound to another wrapper function that gets/runs the function it's currently on (via `.apply()`).  We're just setting the start position it stores before the first `click` event happens, so it finds it and executes the second function on the first pass.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
toggle(function(){ callFunctionOne(); callFunctionTwo(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest such solution:

```
toggle(function(){},secondFunction);

function secondFunction() {}
```

And now you can call it how you want :)